# How to use text() in XPath 1.0 with a suffix?

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

This is what I'm doing to retrieve all texts from XHTML:

```
//p/text()
```

Works fine, but they all go one by one, without any separator. I want to add a space between them. I'm trying:

```
//p/concat(text(), " ")
```

No luck:

```
XPath error : Invalid expression
//p/concat(text(), " ")
           ^
```

I'm using xmllint version 20902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**XPath is really for selection, not manipulation.**  By going beyond selecting text to arranging it to have spacing between the selected items, you're crossing the line from mere selection to manipulation.  **For manipulation, consider XSLT instead of just XPath.**

That said, if you could XPath 2.0 (via another tool -- xmllint supports only XPath 1.0), you can join selected strings together via `string-join()`:

```
 string-join(//p/text(), ' ')
```

Note, however, that `//p/text()` will miss text in `div`, `span` etc.  Perhaps you meant `//*/text()` or `//text()` ?   Note further that even in XPath 1.0, you could get all of the text via `string(/)`, although that won't satisfy your desire to add spaces either.